# Upload multiple files and execute js code on each file

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on this project that takes a number of pictures or images to upload them on the server and executes a javascript code to find a specific `word` on each picture using OCR and write the matched `word` in an Excel sheet in this way:-

this is the picture that we need to upload and read:-
[image: pic]

and this is the code that calls an OCR function and recognizes both words in the red squares
and write down it as an excel table with columns and rows in this shape:-

[image: pic]

so far so good, but the problem is that I need to upload more `pictures` or `images` and read every one to export as a one `table` or `ExcelSheet` with multiple rows for example let's say this is another picture with different values:-
[image]

after uploading it with the first one and executing the javascript function on this picture it should be written with the first picture values on the same excel worksheet `table` like this:-

[image: picture]

as I said I made this code that will upload and read only one picture at once and I did some changes to it so that the client can upload more than one picture and write down the information on one excel file:-

index.php

```
<form id="theform" action="..\upload.php" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return myFunction();" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input id="file" name="uploadedFile[]" type="file" onchange="uptoserver();" style="display:block;" multiple="multiple"  accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div id="buttons" style="display:none !important;">
          <button type="submit"  class="btn wbtn" style="font-family:Hana; font-size:18px; border:1px solid black !important;">
            <img src="..\style\image\camera.png" width="32" />&nbsp;تصوير النمودج&nbsp;
          </button>&nbsp;
          </div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

upload.php

```
<?php
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST')
  {
      echo "Empty data, please select file";
      die;
  }

  if (!isset($_FILES["uploadedFile"]))
  {
      echo "Wrong data struct";
      die;
  }

  if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]['error'][$i] != 0)
  {
    echo "Uploaded data error";
    die;
  }
  $total = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
  $target_dir    = "uploads/";
  $target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]);
  $allowUpload   = true;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $maxfilesize   = 80000000;
  $allowtypes    = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');

for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) { // this for loop is an update for the code to uplaod more than one file

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
      if($check !== false)
      {
          //
      }
      else
      {
          echo "This's not image file.";
          $allowUpload = false;
      }
  }

  if (file_exists($target_file))
  {
      require "other\\fileExsist.php";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }
  if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["size"][$i] > $maxfilesize)
  {
      require "other\\fileSize.php";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }

  if (!in_array($imageFileType,$allowtypes ))
  {
      require "other\\fileExtenstion.php";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }

  if ($allowUpload)
  {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file))
      {
        //   echo "File ". basename( $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]). " uploaded success.";
        //   echo $target_file;
        require "prepare.php";

      }
      else
      {
          echo "Error when upload file.";
      }
  }
  else
  {
      echo "";
  }
}
?>
```

prepare.js (this is called from the prepare.php file)
I did not change anything on this `(reads only one file)`

```
async function readFile(fileName) {
  console.log({ fileName });

  return await Tesseract.recognize(fileName, 'ara', {
  
    logger: m => console.log(m)
  });

}
async function parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, propertyNames) {
  console.log({ text, propertyNames });

  return propertyNames
    .reduce((table, key) =>
      Object.assign(table, {

        [ key ]: RegExp(`${ key }\\W+(\\w+)`)
          .exec(text)?.[1] ?? ''

      }), {});
}
async function writeParsedTextDataAsJSON(fileName, table) {
  console.log({ table });
   JSON.stringify({ table });

  // fake it ...
  return (await new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log({ fileName, json: JSON.stringify({ table }) });
      resolve({ success: true });

    }, 1500)
  ));
}

console.log('... running ...');

async function start(filenames) {
  const { data: { text } } = await readFile(filenames);

  const data = await
    parseDataFromTextAndPropertyNames(text, ['نقطة الخدمة', 'رقم العداد', 'القراءة']);
 document.getElementById("dvjson").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4);
 const final = [JSON.stringify(data)];
 const ff = [JSON.parse(final)];
 constructTable('#table',ff);
 let htmlstring = document.getElementById("table").innerHTML;
 alert(htmlstring);
$.post('change.php', {htmlstring:htmlstring}).done(function(response){
      alert(response);
});
  console.log({ result });
}
```

finally this codes gives me the message `Uploaded data error` when trying to upload one or more pictures

Comment: Are you setting `$i` somewhere? If not change `if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]['error'][$i]` to `if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]['error'][0]`

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles what about the rest

Comment: Once you do that do you get any errors?